# How to convert from xhtml to html5 in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, html, xhtml

I had a aspx page in xhtml. I changed it to html5 by changing the doc tags. However, when I am using header element I see a squiggly line that says Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element header not supported. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have set the html up correctly, it should be able to pick it up that it is html5 without you having to set any IDE options. Could you add the top part of your html to your question, including the `<!doctype>`, `<html>` and  `<head>`, but without any scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your IDE to use HTML 5 standards by going through Tools >> Options menu >> Text Editor >> HTML >> Validation